# How to notify the change in RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Here's my problem:

I have an `AlbumActivity` that lists all the albums name using `RecyclerView`.

When one item is clicked it will go to `ImagesActivity` where all of the images inside the Album will be listed. I also used `RecyclerView`. `ImagesActivity` has a toolbar menu that can add multiple images in case the user wants to add another images to the album. When the menu is clicked another activity will be opened to add images path to the database.

My problem is that when I go back to the `ImagesActivity` the images do not appear. The images will only appear when I only go again to `AlbumActivity` to view again the album's images. How can I notify the change quickly in the `ImagesActivity`.

**Here's my Adapter:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static List<GettersSetters> dbList;
    static Context context;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, List<GettersSetters> dbList) {
        this.dbList = new ArrayList<GettersSetters>();
        this.context = context;
        this.dbList = dbList;

    }

    @Override
    public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_image, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        File imageFile = new File(dbList.get(position).getPath());
        if(imageFile.exists()){
            Bitmap img = decodeBitmapWithSize(dbList.get(position).getPath(),300,150, true);
            holder.imageGallery.setImageBitmap(img);
        }else{
            holder.imageGallery.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_found);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imageGallery;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            imageGallery = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.img_row);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Delete Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

once you add the images, are you calling `notifydatasetchanged()` ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

this needs to be called in your `ImagesActivity` after you add your images to the `dbList`.
Please read the documentation in the above link to understand `notifydatasetchanged()`
This method basically informs the `Adapter` that the data in the `dbList` is updated and hence it has to refresh the UI.

Comment: where do I exactly put the notifyDataSetChanged?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refresh the dbList after add images path to the database.

When you go back to the Images Activity, you get new dbList from database in onActivityResult. And you can refresh the dbList as follows:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...

    public void updateList(List<GettersSetters> dbList) {
        this.dbList.clear();
        this.dbList.addAll(dbList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: in what part of the code do I need to call the updateList?

Comment: After you have updated the List object that you provided to your adapter, you will need to call notifyDataSetChanged().  Say I provided an empty list to my adapter when I created my adapter object, after I add a few objects to that list I will need to call notifyDataSetChanged().  You must call notifyDataSetChanged anytime you delete or add objects from the List attached to your adapter.

Comment: You will call the updateList in onActivityResult on Images Activity.
onActivityResult is called when it go back from menu is clicked another activity.

Comment: @StephenRuda I added an item using Insert query in another Activity?

Comment: @ChristineRamos Well, there are a few ways to do it.  The proposed answer works, but the most common way of doing it is to instantiate your List and Adapter in your activity, and call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter whenever you change the data in the list.  I will post an answer to the question that you can take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of doing it is to instantiate your List and Adapter in your activity, and call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter whenever you change the data in the list.

For example, in your Activity class...

```
List<GetterSetter> list;
ImageAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = new ArrayList();
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, list);
    // you will also need to attach your adapter to your recyclerview.

    // when you are ready to modify/add/delete items from the list, just do it and call notifyDataSetChanged
    list.add(new GetterSetter());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // This will update your recyclerview to show one item, instead of an empty list
}
```

In short, you obviously pass your Adapter a List. Any time you change any data in the list, make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter object.

Answer (score 0):

when coming back to Images Activity in onResume method call like this

```
public void onResume{
youradapter.refreshrecyclerview(); // implement this method in adpater or simply call here
adpater.notifiDataSetChanged();
}
```

In adpater implement this method,

```
public void refreshrecyclerview(){
notifiDataSetChanged();
}
```